# Grunt Task Failing in Visual Studio Team Service (Hosted Agent)

Tags: gruntjs, azure-devops

I have a CI Build setup in VSTS.  One of the tasks is a Grunt Task.  When the task runs it fails with the following output:

> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z ##[section]Starting: grunt build
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z ==============================================================================
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z Task         : Grunt
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z Description  : The JavaScript Task Runner
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z Version      : 0.5.27
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z Help         : [More
> Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627413)
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:44.8952691Z ==============================================================================
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:45.2362520Z [command]C:\NPM\Modules\grunt.cmd build
> --gruntfile d:\a\1\s\Solution\Project\Gruntfile.js
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.3905419Z grunt-cli: The grunt command line
> interface (v1.2.0)
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.3905419Z
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.3905419Z Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.4895387Z  2017-06-14T18:00:47.4895387Z If you're
> seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.4895387Z your project. For more information about
> installing and configuring grunt,
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.4895387Z please
> see the Getting Started guide:
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.4895387Z
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.4895387Z http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.6415301Z ##[error]Grunt failed with error:
> C:\NPM\Modules\grunt.cmd failed with return code: 99
>
> 2017-06-14T18:00:47.6475300Z ##[section]Finishing: grunt build

The Build Definition has

> Grunt Exists

in the demands.

I am using the "Hosted" Agent Queue.  When I look at the "Hosted" Agent Capabilities it has:

> grunt C:\NPM\Modules\grunt.cmd

listed.

Why is the build agent failing saying that it cannot find grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **grunt-cli** that can be execute **grunt** command, but you still need to install grunt package to the working folder (e.g. project folder)

Simple sample:

1. Add **npm** task (working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`;  npm command: `install`; arguments:`grunt`)
2. Add **Grunt** task (working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`; Grunt File Path: `[gruntfile.js file relative path of $(build.sourcesdirectory)` )